# Viewing category won't show up Custom post type posts

Tags: posts, categories

I'm having a strange problem:

I've build a category page and want to load up all related posts of a custom post type but won't give any results. I'm using the following code:

```
  query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'blog', 'showposts' => 3, 'cat' => 9 ) );
```

When deleting the 'cat' it shows all posts of the custom post type.

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Blockquote

**Taxonomy** *category* with a **term** with *id* 9 dosen't have a posts with **post type** *blog*.

Are you sure that you using native category taxonomy for CPT blogs posts?

```
function query_report($sql){
    var_dump($sql);
    echo '<hr>';
    return $sql;
}
add_filter('query', 'query_report');
query_posts($your_arguments);
remove_filter('query', 'query_report');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Code Monkey,

I'm not sure.. how can I find out I'm using the regular category? This is in my CTP functions.php:

      'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', 'category'),

Comment: well if you sure (let think that its support) try to query taxonomy term by slug (in case of category its - **category_name**) `query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'blog', 'showposts' => 3, 'category_name' =>  'slug') );`

Comment: Thanks again Code Monkey, nothing appears after your code so it looks like it's not supported?

Comment: Looks like posts from content type blogs dosen't have relation to category you specifing... or its overiten by some filter/action hook. did category apears at the backend as selected whan you editing one of that "blogs" posts?

Comment: They are selected when I'm creating or editing the post. When viewing the posts of 'blog' and clicking a category they won't popup in the results. So some function is blocking this?

Comment: loosk like that. check the debug code (basicly sql statments that generated by query posts function) - if you familar with SQL you shoud, be able on eye determine whats wrong with query. And after that will be understand - do your wp has categories assosiations with posts or not. and if its exists you can debug more to get an idea what's rewriting your query.

Comment: Found the problem in my functions.php. Thanks for helping out Code Monkey!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this code was bugging in my function.php:

```
<?php function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) { 'if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {`
$query->set( 'post_type', array(
 'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'apps'
    ));
  return $query;
} } add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' ); ?>
```

Problem solved, thanks Code Monkey!